# Is anyone exempt from law of karma?

Tags: philosophy, karma

Does the law of karma applies to the millions of **gods and goddesses** and **avatars**?

Comment: Saguna brahman is exempt from the law of karma. Same with incarnations of Saguna brahman. Different sAmpradAyas have different ideas of who Saguna brahman is. Therefore, it is likely that one can get contradictory answers on which gods/goddessess/avatars are exempt.

Comment: The answer to your question is yes.

Comment: Alternatively, you may ask "Is law of karma Universal? Does it apply to all non aatman entities equally? The answer would be yes. Even Brahma, Shiva and Vishnu are not exempt. You must have heard different shraap they get, or have to take avatars etc. All part of karma.

Comment: I guess in the Bhagavad Gita,Lord Krishna talks about how He is not bound by the law of Karma,but he does it anyhow so as to set an example for humans...

Comment: I think it applies to everyone and no exceptions